# How to store creation date in a new table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am building a database that stores information about employees in one table named employees and I want to store log info in another table named log info. 
The log info should contain the creator's name, creation and modification date.

What values should I use and how can I make the creation date unchangeable?

Because I don't want to store it in the employees table, is there a way when an entry is created on the employees's table to automatically change date and time on the other table.
This has to be done only through code or I can do it with SQL statements only?

This is the database specifications. How should I split data?

Main data:

- Name
- Birthdate
- ID
- Is an employee
- Contact info(e-mail, phone, address)

The following information in English, Spanish and French:

- Introduction
- Working Experince
- Education Info

Log info:

- Who and when created the entry
- Who and when last modified the data

Comment: `This has to be done only through code or I can do it with SQL statements only?` Given you have access to both you can do it in both way.

Comment: This is a pretty general question about how to use SQL in the end. The answers can be found in the documentation. In general you cannot really make an entry write-only in the strict sense, that is against the idea of a relation database. Instead you have to keep such permission stuff on the application level. You can use `triggers` to automatically make entries in the log table. But maybe writing a manual entry is sufficient in this case.

Comment: What is better in general?Through code or through SQL. Anyone knows how it is done through SQL and phpmyadmin?

Comment: I created one table for employees, 3 tables for the info in each language and a log info table. Should I put log info in the employees table or leave it as a separate table?

Comment: I updated my question, can you help on how should I split data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mysql triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) for example create logging table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `log_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

assuming that your employees table has an employee_name column and an id primary key, you can create a trigger on it that automatically gets executed after a name is inserted:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER loginsert AFTER INSERT ON employee_name
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_info SET emp_id=NEW.id, entry_time= NOW();
  END;
|
```

This will allow you to use a different table for the logging stuff, you can also insert more data into the log_info table like the key of the inserted employee, who inserted the record etc... just check the docs for all the syntax.

Comment: So, can I use this trigger on another table or has to be on the same one?

Comment: Yea, I've edited the answer to add an example of the log_info table. The trigger is added to the table that it listens to for changes(employee) but it can work on any table in the database, including employees table again. It is also not limited to working on one table at at time

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought on using the emp_id from employees table as a primary key in the log_info table, because every log_info entry should belong to the employee with the same id. Should I do that or use another field as an id as you suggest?

Comment: Yes, i didn't think of that. On the other hand it is a limitation and you don't know how it might limit you in future, just in case.

Comment: Why is it a limitation? Every employee in the employees table has an emp_id and an id number which are unique. Every employee should have one and only entry in the others table (info_en, info_sp, info_fr and log_info), so I used emp_id as a foreign key on the other tables  and set it as a primary key . You think is this a correct approach or change my design?

Comment: No am just saying in the usage of the log_info table, for example you may want to reuse the table to log actions on another table, not employees. But if you are using it for just employee logging then that is OK

Answer (score 2):

You declare a column as `timestamp` or `datetime` and initialize it.  Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The MySQL documentation has a long explanation on how to do this [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

EDIT:

I think you should really store the creation date in the same table that the data is stored in.  That seems logical, and it is how I design basically all my tables.

If you really want to put this in another table, then you can use an `insert` trigger to insert a row in the other table every time a row is inserted in the first table.  As a note, I have never used this approach.  I always put such creation dates in the table with the data.

Comment: So, if I set a field as date_created as DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP CURRENT_TIMESTAMP this value won't change every time the entry is modified?

Comment: @Andreas777 . . . No, once it is set, it is set.  This is true of almost all default values.  The exception is for updates.  If you want an update time, then use the `on update` clause in the definition.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I 'm new on database design and this about times confuses me. This is project I have to create a database about employees and storing some info and the storing creation date and modification date. You know if I can do it through phpmyadmin or only from code?

Comment: You put these lines in the `create table` statement.  They are in the database and they just work.  When creating tables, I also often put in the user who created the table in a column.  In MySQL I think you can use `current_user()` for that.

Comment: "Because I don't want to store it in the employees table" ->This solution uses the same table for logging creation date